# Regarding Android Progress Bar working

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a doubt regarding progress bar in android. I haven't implemented it yet but due to shortage of time i want to make sure when i implement i better be clear with what is going to happen and why..

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        // set the progress to be horizontal
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        // reset the bar to the default value of 0
        dialog.setProgress(0);

        // get the maximum value
        EditText max = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.maximum);
        // convert the text value to a integer
        int maximum = Integer.parseInt(max.getText().toString());
        // set the maximum value
        dialog.setMax(maximum);
        // display the progressbar
        dialog.show();

        // create a thread for updating the progress bar
        Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               try {
                   // enter the code to be run while displaying the progressbar.
                   //
                   // This example is just going to increment the progress bar:
                   // So keep running until the progress value reaches maximum value
                   while (dialog.getProgress()<= dialog.getMax()) {
                       // wait 500ms between each update
                       Thread.sleep(500);

                       // active the update handler
                       progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                   }
               } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
                   // if something fails do something smart
               }
           }
        });

        // start the background thread
        background.start();

    }

    // handler for the background updating
    Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
        }
    };
```

This is the above code i took from somewhere...As this code says i have to keep my actual code below try in order to keep progress bar running.. My doubt is my code is a very lengthy one consisting of nested for loops ( parsing an entire file with all those bits and bytes) .. if i keep my lengthy process at that part of the section, how can it update the progress bar until it finishes its task ?
Am i missing some concept ? please explain me how can i keep my process running and also update progress bar?

Answer (score 1):

You should use AsynTask and show your ProgreesBar in its `onPreExecute()` method and dismiss the ProgressBar in its `onPostExecute()` method. Do all your Loading Stuff in `doInBackground()` method.Further, to update ProgressBar use `onProgressUpdate()`

This will help : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept that you are missing is that if you want to to multiple things (showing progress in a progress bar and doing some actual work) you need to use multiple threads. That is why you need to create a separate thread to do the actual work.

And even if your code is really length, try re-factoring it, splitting it up into new classes and methods.

Comment: so u mean to say if keep my nested for loops in that section, progress bar will keep updating cause of multiple threads?

Comment: It should still be animated because you are doing the work in a separate thread. However, you still need to tell the main thread your progress through the progress handler somewhere in your nested loops.